# Excel 2003: Save unicode spreadsheet as normal spreadsheet to retain formatting (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, excel-2003

My code opens a unicode .xls file exported from SAP, does some filtering and color-coding of cells, then attempts this:

```
.SaveAs Filename:=srcpath & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "file.xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal
```

Also tried

```
.SaveAs Filename:=srcpath & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "file.xls", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
```

Also tried

```
.SaveAs Filename:=srcpath & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "file.xls", FileFormatNum:=-4143
```

I know the string "srcpath" and dating bit are okay since the save happens, but I get no formatting because it's still a unicode file! This is in 2003 btw. Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Comment: By unicode .xls file you mean a text file?  I can load a text file, format it and save it complete with formatting with your statement providing I include a "\" at the end of srcpath.  Are you looking at the wrong file because the file you have just saved is one directory up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was elsewhere in my code, one of those situations where the debugger misleads you because there's an if statement or something.  For the record, this works just fine in 2003:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=srcpath & c & " file.xls", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
```

where "c" is some string you want in the filename; in my case today's date.